# Java JExcel encoding to Utf-8

Tags: java, excel, encoding, utf-8

We have an old app here that writes xls files that is read from other files. The problem I face is that the encoding doesnt get transported over to the newly created .xls, it skips all special characters (ÅÄÖ, im Scandinavian).

Ive tried setting the new workbook to Utf-8 with no success, see code below:

```
File f = new File(pathName + fileName + ".csv");
System.out.println(splitName[1]);
if(f.exists())
    f.delete();
OutputStream os = (OutputStream) new FileOutputStream(f);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "Utf-8");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));
ws.setEncoding("Utf-8");
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(pathName + fileName + ".xls"), ws);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Writing to the .csv is okay (though could be shorter) - I use "UTF-8" which seems everyone does. Hence the workbook is read wrong somehow. Try `ws.setEncoding("Windows-1252");`.

Comment: Thank you, however, that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe `ws.setEncoding("Cp252"); ws.setExcelDisplayLanguage("sv"); ws.setExcelRegionalSettings("SE"); ... new Locale("sv", "SE")` - maybe EN, English, reverts to ASCII.

Comment: Hi @JoopEggen,

Thank you for the input, however it does not work. Ive tried setting the locale etc, also changed the replaceAll regex to `[^\\p{ASCII}a-zA-ZÄäÖöØøÆæ ]`.

Also shortened the writer:

    `String encoding = "UTF-8";
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f), encoding));
    WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
    ws.setLocale(new Locale("no", "NO"));
    ws.setEncoding(encoding);
    ws.setExcelRegionalSettings("NO");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(pathName + fileName + ".xls"), ws);`

Comment: What do you instead of your chars? Question marks, squares or some repeating symbols (ex. `Р°Р±РІ`)